# Disable cache in google chrome (Mac) for developing in flex/flash

Tags: apache-flex, google-chrome, flex3, adobe, cache-control

What is the best way to go about disabling the cache in google chrome for mac, so that when I am developing a flash application, it will bring in the new movie every time?

Please advise, I can't figure out how to ensure the version of the .swf I am looking at is the most recent version.

One solution might be to get the flex compiler to append a timestamp to the .swf filenames, is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the 'View' menu, open Developer Tools.  In the bottom right corner of the Developer Tools is a gear icon.  Click it, then check the 'Disable Cache' checkbox.

Comment: This wasn't an option when I originally posted it, but now it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In your embed code where ever you the swf file you have to put a random number or a time stamp of some sort on the query. Whenever there is a query string that changes the browser will not cache the page.

```
"MySWFName.swf?t=" + new Date().getTime();
```

Best method would be to embed your SWF using SWFObject with this code.

In the html body tag do this.

```
<body onLoad="loaded()" onunload"doUnload( )">
  <div id="replaceMe">Loading content.</div>
</body>
```

and for the javascript do this ( obviously changing the stuff wrapped in **{ }** to your needs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loaded() {
    var flashvars={}, params={}, attributes={}, tmp, version, width, height, container, flashObj;
    flashvars.userName    = "testvar";

    params.menu = "true";
    params.quality = "high";
    params.bgcolor = "${bgcolor}";
    params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
    params.allownetworking = "all";

    attributes.id = "${application}";
    attributes.name = "${application}";
    attributes.align = "middle";
    attributes.allowscriptaccess = "always";
    attributes.allownetworking = "all";

    tmp = "expressInstall.swf";
    version = "${version_major}.${version_minor}.${version_revision}";
    width = "${width}";
    height = "${height}";
    container = "replaceMe";
    flashObj = "${swf}.swf?t=" + new Date().getTime();
    swfobject.embedSWF(flashObj, container, width, height, version, tmp, flashvars, params, attributes);
  }
</script>
```

Don't forget to add a copy of SWFobject
You will never have caching issues again


EDIT:
BTW if you replace your code in your html.template.html file with this code it will generate the values for you. :)

Comment: I like it, but I think I am going to use rails to solve this. If the mode is development it will put the timestamp, if not, no timestamp! Thanks!

Comment: You should still use SWFObject to embed your swf rails or no rails. this is the line that is key to what you are doing just put an if else statement for your modes and remove the time stamp flashObj = "${swf}.swf?t=" + new Date().getTime();

Comment: I've always used swfobject. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would never do that.  Caching is there for a reason and shouldn't be disabled when you're running it locally.  In my experience, the best way to do it is have a 'version' (normally a static properly in a Class) number increment every time you build (by using Ant or Maven; even better if you have an automation engine to do it too) which then attached that version number as a url parameter for the flash movie like `Movie.swf?version=1.31` in the html.

Comment: That's absurd.  You're saying that every single loading operation should append something to the URL just to ease development?  There are plenty of good reasons to disable the cache when developing.